# Ideas for setting up a network in my clinic

Tags: windows, windows-xp, networking

I have a clinic with 6 machines connecting to a server. All these machines use Windows XP. It's a desktop application for recording patient activities.

5 machines are active throughout the day, but all they do is just enter records into the server. All these machines have a CPU which takes up power resources.

I want to make these machines thin clients with just an interface and all processing should take place on the server. How can I make this possible, involving least costs?

Comment: Does the application *need* to run on Windows?

Comment: yes please since I have WinXP

Answer (score 4):

Your 5 data-entry machines are already sunk costs, and they already have processors that are central to their operation, and there's no way around that. Even if you made them into a kind of virtual terminal using Citrix or something, they'd still be running their processors. And honestly, the extra layer of abstraction would probably make them use more processor power rather than less.

I don't see a way to save money here until these systems reach the end of their lifecycle. Then you could replace them with the cheapest, lowest-power, dumbest terminals your patient-activity-recording software can support.  Until then, I doubt that the electricity cost savings would outweigh the cost of replacing the PC hardware with thin clients or dumb terminals that use less power.  On the other hand, going to a non-Windows-PC solution could probably save administrative costs (less sysadmin work and no malware or other security worries/costs with diskless dumb terminals that don't run a well-known, often-attacked OS). But does your patient activity recording software run on anything other than Windows?

Comment: Spiff thanks for the quick answer. Absolute newbie here. Can a PC monitor be converted to a virtual terminal? If Citrix is used, why is a processor required? Do we have some special monitors that act as virtual terminals or our normal PC monitors will do? I have those real old monitors with a big box and not the LCD ones.

Comment: @Russ: How are you supposed to run the client without a CPU?

Comment: Hmm I saw a setup in one of the offices where there were only monitors and no CPU and the processing was done on the server. The monitors just had an application interface and people were punching data in it. I am sure there's was no CPU. That's how I got the idea.

Comment: @RussT You're probably vastly overestimating the cost of running those computers. It likely amounts to $50-$150 per year, and you'd only be able to save at most 75% of that. Considering the 3-5 year lifespan of a typical computer you'd save $560 per PC in an optimal scenario. A server capable of running 5+ thin clients and your application is going to chew up the potential savings instantly. What your proposing is certainly possible, and there are various advantages to such a setup, but cost ain't one of them typically.

Comment: @Spiff "non-Windows-PC solution could probably save administrative costs" <-- *nix admins make more on average than Windows admins. I see more attacks on port 22 than 145 in my logs. The generally accepted rule is that Windows has higher CapEx and *nix has higher OpEx.

Comment: Upboat (oops, leaking reddit) for Chris S. Realize that the security advantages of *nix disappear in server installations. The majority of servers run Linux = the majority of people trawling the internet for vulnerable servers are tooled up for Linux. Just something to think about when you're exposing a machine to the internet. I don't care what OS it runs, if it accepts connections from the internet it's going to be trouble.

Comment: Also, more on topic: a company that I used to work for dealt in several different types of thin-client solutions that we targeted towards this situation. There were a lot of cool things about them (ease of administration, flexible load planning, etc) but price was not one of them. Plan on a thin-client solution costing more initially than a conventional one (except in very large environments, where you can plan on it costing around the same). Maintenance will be lower, but when we're talking 5 clients you'll never make the investment back.

Answer (score 2):

There's plenty of new thin-client solutions available (again) these days.

It's being referred to as [Desktop Virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_virtualization).  This is provided/supported by your "VDI" (Virtual Desktop Infrastructure).

The "easiest" is going to be a basic RDS ([Windows Remote Desktop Services](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server/remote-desktop-services.aspx)).  I say "easiest" based on you saying you already have "a server" and "Windows", and thick clients.  You can replace most of the thick clients with pretty cheap 'thin-clients' these days, on a need-to basis.

Your program has to be multi-user aware (so people's settings don't get mixed upon the server), and it's graphical needs would need to be considered.

If you need (or software requires) separation of machines, then you may need to consider Virtual Machine solutions along with Virtual Desktop.

Check out [VMWare's View](http://www.vmware.com/products/view/overview.html) (with PCoIP), as well as [MS's MultiPoint](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/multipoint/) solutions and various "[Zero Client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client#Recent_trends)" options (clients with no CPU).  Windows 2008R2 with an advanced RDS setups will get you most of the way as well.  Let's also not forget [Citrix](http://www.citrix.com/lang/english/home.asp).

Then remember all your peripherals.  All printers, label printers, and scanners (etc.) will need to be network attached, especially as the clients get 'thinner'.

Costing will vary on what you need, have, and want. ;)